# Tomcat 7 ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I bought a SSL certificate from certum.pl to run java (jdk 1.8) web application on tomcat 7 using SSL and https.

I created jks file using keytool:

```
keytool -importcert -file "certificate.cer" -keystore "file.jks" -alias "mycert" -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048
```

My tomcat configuration:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on"/>

<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="443"/>

<Connector
            protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
            port="443"
            maxThreads="200"
            connectionUploadTimeout="36000000"
            disableUploadTimeout="false"
            connectionTimeout="60000"
            scheme="https"
            secure="true"
            SSLEnabled="true"
            keystoreFile="${catalina.home}/conf/file.jks"
            keystorePass="pass"
            clientAuth="false"
            sslProtocol="TLS"
            maxPostSize="52428800"
            ciphers="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
            TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
            TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
            TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
            TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
    />
```

When calling `https://mywebsite/` in firefox, it throws 'ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap' and also in chrome it 'ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH'.

> **Note:** It works with a self-signed keystore but when I use my verified certificate it's not working.

I'm struggling with that issue for 2 days :(

Any help will be appreciated in advance.

Comment: Why don't you try removing the entries in "ciphers" in the "connector" block until you can pinpoint the cipher that is causing this issue?

Comment: I've delete the entries one by one and finally remove 'ciphers' but nothing changed. Might this issue be related to the certificate CA? Or I choose wrong cipher entry? I'm confused by this.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is SSLProtocol=TLS is not officially documented in tomcat7. You might want to leave this attribute or use one of the documented values.